# Cannot find DbContext class using dotnet ef migrations add Initial -s <project> -c <full class name from referenced project> -o <output dir>

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to learn how to generate migrations using dotnet core Entity Framework.

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API project that references two projects, each containing a DBContext.

I have successfully managed to generate the migrations for one dbcontext using:

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial -s <startup_project> -c <fully qualified class name from referenced project> -o <output dir>
```

However, for the second DbContext it fails to find the DbContext with the message:
`No DbContext named 'dcs3spp.courseManagementContainers.BuildingBlocks.IntegrationEventLogEF.IntegrationEventLogContext' was found.`

The project file for the referenced project has the path correctly referenced with contents:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\EventBus\EventBus.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.1">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="3.1.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

The project file for the ASP.NET Core Web API startup project is:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Courses.Domain\Courses.Domain.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Courses.Infrastructure\Courses.Infrastructure.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\BuildingBlocks\EventBus\EventBus\EventBus.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\BuildingBlocks\EventBus\IntegrationEventLogEF\IntegrationEventLogEF.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\BuildingBlocks\WebHost.Customization\WebHost.Customization.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\BuildingBlocks\EventBus\EventBusRabbitMQ\EventBusRabbitMQ.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.HealthChecks.AzureServiceBus" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.HealthChecks.Npgsql" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.HealthChecks.Rabbitmq" Version="3.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.Client" Version="3.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.30" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.1">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="4.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="3.1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Polly" Version="7.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" Version="2.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Http" Version="5.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Seq" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reflection" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>


</Project>
```

The source code for the context class that cannot be found is:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace dcs3spp.courseManagementContainers.BuildingBlocks.IntegrationEventLogEF
{
    public class IntegrationEventLogContext : DbContext
    {       
        public IntegrationEventLogContext(DbContextOptions<IntegrationEventLogContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<IntegrationEventLogEntry> IntegrationEventLogs { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {          
            builder.Entity<IntegrationEventLogEntry>(ConfigureIntegrationEventLogEntry);
        }

        void ConfigureIntegrationEventLogEntry(EntityTypeBuilder<IntegrationEventLogEntry> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("IntegrationEventLog");

            builder.HasKey(e => e.EventId);

            builder.Property(e => e.EventId)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(e => e.Content)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(e => e.CreationTime)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(e => e.State)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(e => e.TimesSent)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(e => e.EventTypeName)
                .IsRequired();
        }
    }
}
```

The Startup.cs of the ASP.NET Core Web API project adds the DB Contexts is as follows:

```cs
services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
                   .AddDbContext<CourseContext>(options =>
                   {
                       options.UseNpgsql(configuration["ConnectionString"],
                           npgsqlOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                           {
                               sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name);
                               sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: 15, maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), errorCodesToAdd: null);
                           });
                   },
                       ServiceLifetime.Scoped  //Showing explicitly that the DbContext is shared across the HTTP request scope (graph of objects started in the HTTP request)
                   );

            services.AddDbContext<IntegrationEventLogContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseNpgsql(configuration["ConnectionString"],
                                     npgsqlOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                                     {
                                         sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name);
                                         //Configuring Connection Resiliency: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency 
                                         sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: 15, maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), errorCodesToAdd: null);
                                     });
            });
```

Is it possible to generate migrations for many DbContext subclasses from within a startup project?

If so, what are the potential causes of not been able to find a DBContext class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by implementing an instance of [IDesignTimeDbContextFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design.idesigntimedbcontextfactory-1?view=efcore-3.1). Found this solution after reading [this](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/issues/1080#issuecomment-504665885)

Now when I run...

`dotnet ef migrations add Initial -s <startup_project> -c <fully.qualified.context.class.name> -o <output dir>`

EntityFrameworkCore locates my second context class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to create a code-first database from two different DbContext which are pointed to one database - only a single context can do that.

I would suggest you make a one common DbContext which is only responsible for creating the database. Then you can create your real application contexts that contain subsets from the big one.

***Is it possible to generate migrations for many DbContext subclasses from within a startup project?***

It is possible to generate migrations for many DbContext subclasses in case they are pointed to different databases.

***What are the potential causes of not been able to find a DBContext class?***

From the error that you have showed I see that you are looking for the namespace, not for the current DbContext class.

'dcs3spp.courseManagementContainers.BuildingBlocks.IntegrationEventLogEF' should be 'dcs3spp.courseManagementContainers.BuildingBlocks.IntegrationEventLogEF.IntegrationEventLogContext'

Comment: +10 Ooops, copy and paste error did not copy full namespace into question......tried again just in case but still fails to find the context class, same message. Based the  the code on [Microsoft's eshopContainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/Services/Ordering/Ordering.API/Startup.cs#L232)